# Some application icons are not shown on Plasma under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, icons, plasma, plasma-5

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, I installed `kubuntu-desktop`. In Plasma 5, icons for certain applications (including Firefox and Thunderbird) are not appearing on the application launcher or task manager while the applications are closed, while they do appear on the task manager when the applications are running. I am currently using the Breeze-Dark icon set, and I do not experience this issue on the Unity desktop environment.

Application Launcher not loading icons for various applications:
[image: Application Launcher not loading icons for various applications]

Task manager with Thunderbird closed and Firefox open:
[image: Task manager with Thunderbird closed and Firefox open]

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution?

Comment: I am no longer looking for the solution. Since asking the question, I have ditched the installation that was causing the issue so I can't confirm whether the answer worked in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too, but I found a fix! Well, a workaround...

What you want to do is find on your computer or on the internet the missing icons, and put them in a folder (try to find 256x256 icons), for example Pictures/custom-icons.

Then, you copy all those icons in the folder `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps`

To do so, open a terminal and enter `sudo cp -a /home/YOURUSERNAME/Pitcures/custom-icons/. /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps`

You now have working icons! To apply them, right click on the application launcher and select *edit application*. Now, select the application you want and click on the empty box, next to the name field. Choose *System icons -> Applications*, and enter the name of your icon.

Hope it helps!